# Extracting 7z files as String fails with ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException -1

Tags: java, 7zip

I am trying to extract 7z file containing XMLs as String, I am using below code:

```js
private static String getXML( InputStream in )
  {
    String content = null;
    try
    {
      
      ByteArrayOutputStream contentBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

      // ... using a small buffer byte array.
      byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
      int bytesRead;
      while ( ( bytesRead = in.read( buffer ) ) != -1 )
      {
        contentBytes.write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
      }
      // Assuming the content is a UTF-8 text file we can interpret the
      // bytes as a string.
      content = contentBytes.toString( "UTF-8" );
    }

    catch ( IOException e )
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content;
  }
```

and calling it from main function as:

```js
while ( ( entry = stream.getNextEntry() ) != null )
      {

        //SevenZArchiveEntry entry = ( SevenZArchiveEntry ) newEntries.nextElement();
        /*while (newEntries.hasMoreElements()){
          SevenZArchiveEntry entry = ( SevenZArchiveEntry ) newEntries.nextElement();*/
        System.out.println( "Entered in for loop" );
        System.out.println( entry.getName() );

        if ( !entry.isDirectory() )
        {
          
          String extractedXML = getXML( stream.getInputStream( entry ) ).toString();
          
          //do some XML processing
        //entry = stream.getNextEntry();
      }
      }
```

but it does not even get inside the getXML function and gives me below exception:

**java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.buildDecodingStream(SevenZFile.java:1175)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.getInputStream(SevenZFile.java:1351)
at com.heiler.ppm.custom.import5.partnerfeed.hotfolder.core.Unzip7z.unzipFiles(Unzip7z.java:183)
at com.heiler.ppm.custom.import5.partnerfeed.hotfolder.core.Unzip7z.execute(Unzip7z.java:107)
at com.heiler.ppm.importer5.inbox.core.internal.preImportStep.PreImportStep.execute(PreImportStep.java:257)
at com.heiler.ppm.importer5.inbox.server.internal.job.InboxJob.executePreImportStep(InboxJob.java:520)
at com.heiler.ppm.importer5.inbox.server.internal.job.InboxJob.executePreImportSteps(InboxJob.java:432)
at com.heiler.ppm.importer5.inbox.server.internal.job.InboxJob.executePreImportStepsAndScheduleImports(InboxJob.java:352)
at com.heiler.ppm.importer5.inbox.server.internal.job.InboxJob.run(InboxJob.java:215)
at com.heiler.ppm.job.server.internal.ServerJobExecutorRunnable.runJob(ServerJobExecutorRunnable.java:190)
at com.heiler.ppm.job.server.internal.ServerJobExecutorRunnable.run(ServerJobExecutorRunnable.java:123)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)**

Could someone please guide or point where am I going wrong? Any leads would be highly appreciated.